# Responsive CSS iPhone etc

Tags: css, iphone, height, width, responsiveness

Hi for some reason my responsive CSS is not working, I'm not sure what to change or what to do, but whenever I load my site up on my iPhone and zoom all the way out the site only uses up approx 3/4 of the page, I have no idea why, here's the code in my CSS.

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
.navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

.navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tp-banner-container {
    padding-top:40px;
}

.page-scroll a.btn-circle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 7px 0;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
}   
}
```

I've the max width to 767 as that's the width of a iPhone to test it out, but no matter what I seem to change nothing happens.

Comment: clear cache and cookies?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your html and css. I think the issue could be a parent div wrapping the page elements.